# A cyclic group of order $n$ can be generated by $a^k$ if $(k,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am trying to provide a solution to the following exercise. Please point out anything that you find wrong and/or bad.

> Show that a cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ generated by an element $a$ can also be generated by $a^k$ if $k$ and $p$ are relatively prime.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Any element of $G$ can be written as

$$a^x,\,1\leq x\leq n$$

We are trying to show the following

$$\left(a^k\right)^m=a^x\,\,\, (\textrm{mod}\,\,n)$$

where $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and $m$ is some integer less than $n$. By Bézout's Identity,

$$(k,n)=1\implies ak+bn=1$$

$$\begin{align*}
\rightarrow (xa)k+(xb)n&=x\\
(m)k+(\beta)n&=x\\
(m)k&=(-\beta)n+x\\
mk&=\alpha n +x\\
&\\
\implies mk&=x\,\,\,(\textrm{mod}\,\,n)
\end{align*}
$$

We have found our integer $m$ that satisfies the equality. It is left to show that each $(a^k)^m$ for $1\leq m \leq n$ is a **distinct** member of $G$. Note that if $m\geq n$, then $m=qn+b$ for some positive integers $q$ and $b$, where $1\leq b \leq n$. This means that

$$\left(a^k\right)^m=\left(a^k\right)^{qn+b}=a^{(kq)n}a^{kb}=(e)a^{kb}=\left(a^k\right)^b$$

And so the situation is reduced back to the original one. Thus, because $(a^k)^m$ covers every element in $G$ for $1\leq m\leq n$, there is a bijection between the group generated by $a^k$ and $G$. $\blacksquare$.

Comment: It's a fine proof. Just the fact that all $(a^k)^m$ are distinct. Not sure it's necessary, as each $a^x$ is attained (don't forget for finite sets with the same cardinal, surjective implies injective).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially correct.

Faster:
Note that since $(k, n)=1$, $\exists p,q$ such that $pk + qn = 1$. But then
$$
a^{pk + qn} = a \\
\implies a^{pk} \cdot a^{qn} = a
$$
but $a^{qn} = 1$, so
$$
a^{pk} = a,
$$
and $a$ generates the cyclic group, so $a^k$ does too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ a^k\,$ has order $\,\color{#c00}{n/(k,n)}\,$ by basic gcd laws (below). $ $ But $\,n/(k,n) = n\iff (k,n)= 1.$

$$a^{kj} = 1 \iff n\mid kj \iff  n\mid kj,nj \iff n\mid (kj,nj) = (k,n)j \iff \color{#c00}{n/(k,n)}\mid j\qquad $$